# How do I pass in optional flags and parameters to bash script?

Tags: bash, unix

I have a bash script that I pass parameters into (and access via $1). This parameter is a single command that must be processed (i.e. git pull, checkout dev, etc.).

I run my script like `./script_name git pull`

Now, I want to add an optional flag to my script to do some other functionality. So if I call my script like `./script_name -t git pull` it will have a different functionality from `./script_name git pull`.

How do I access this new flag along with the parameters passed in. I've tried using getopts, but can't seem to make it work with the other non-flag parameters that are passed into the script.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using getopts is indeed the way to go:

```
has_t_option=false
while getopts :ht opt; do
    case $opt in 
        h) show_some_help; exit ;;
        t) has_t_option=true ;;
        :) echo "Missing argument for option -$OPTARG"; exit 1;;
       \?) echo "Unknown option -$OPTARG"; exit 1;;
    esac
done

# here's the key part: remove the parsed options from the positional params
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

# now, $1=="git", $2=="pull"

if $has_t_option; then
    do_something
else
    do_something_else
fi
```